# What's the difference between 'coding=utf8' and '-*- coding: utf-8 -*-'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

Is there any difference between using

```
#coding=utf8
```

and

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

What about

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no difference; Python recognizes all 3. It looks for the pattern:

```
coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)
```

on the first two lines of the file (which also must start with a `#`).

That's the literal text 'coding', followed by either a colon or an equals sign, followed by optional whitespace. Any word, dash or dot characters following that pattern are read as the codec.

The `-*-` is an [Emacs-specific syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html); letting the text editor know what encoding to use. It makes the comment useful to *two* tools. VIM supports [similar syntax](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic).

See [PEP 263: Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: Are there (brief and uncontested) views on what style is preferred (or used most commonly)?

Comment: None that I am aware of.