# SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

If I try to use a magic comment like `#coding=utf-8` on top of a file, here's what happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <string>, line 0
SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string
```

I really haven't done anything wrong. Here is the code:

```
#coding=utf-8

string = raw_input()
chars = {}
for i in string:
    if i in chars:
        chars[i] += 1
    else:
        chars[i] = 0
print chars
```

I use repl.it.

Comment: it's `encoding`, not `coding`.

Comment: @DeepSpace See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263). Of course it can be `coding`!

Comment: @DeepSpace: no it isn't. It  could be `decoding`, or `flubcoding`, or just `coding`. The regex used doesn't care. See [What's the difference between 'coding=utf8' and '-\*- coding: utf-8 -\*-'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302074)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, good to know!

Comment: Are you using exec to run this by any chance? The error message would not make sense otherwise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is `exec` the problem? I use repl.it Python 2, maybe it runs the code with `exec`. If you think you have got a solution, please answer.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: yes, I expect `repl.it` to be using exec. Environments like that should *always* be mentioned when you encounter weird issues, it may be that they are unique to that environment (as they are here).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I only know from experience. I tried to run the statement `print open(__import__('sys').argv[0]).read()` to read the interpreter's code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You omitted something from your question: You are using `exec` to execute this code. And you passed a *Unicode object* to exec, which means you already have stated that the source is Unicode text:

```
>>> code = '''\
... # coding=utf8
... print 'hello world!'
... '''
>>> exec code
hello world!
>>> exec code.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0
SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string
```

You can't use a PEP 263 declaration in Unicode text passed to `exec`.

If you are using a 'custom' environment like [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python), then yes, such environments invariably use tricks like `exec` to execute code, and they load the source code as Unicode from your browser. See the [actual code used](https://repl.it/Crfs), which passes JSON-sourced strings to `exec` (where such strings are always going to be `unicode` strings).

Comment: I think the interpreter uses `exec`. Thanks in advance! +1

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: it does, on Unicode strings loaded from JSON; the actual script is readily available when reading `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: [I know about `sys.argv[0]`.](/q/39142304/39142445#comment65629227_39142304)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος:  I didn't mean to imply you didn't, sorry.